# Using thumb to move element

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Trying to move an element using thumbs drag delta (This is in the elements class)
E.g:

```
Private Sub MVEthumb_DragDelta(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs)
    Me.Margin = New Thickness(Me.Margin.Left + e.HorizontalChange, Me.Margin.Top + e.HorizontalChange, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this only causes the element to move diagonally (NWSE) whereas I need it to move in all directions (not just from NW to SE).

Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated, Red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo - you add `e.HorizontalChange` both to left and top.

```
Me.Margin = New Thickness(Me.Margin.Left + e.HorizontalChange, Me.Margin.Top + e.HorizontalChange, 0, 0)
```

should be:

```
Me.Margin = New Thickness(Me.Margin.Left + e.HorizontalChange, Me.Margin.Top + e.VerticalChange, 0, 0)
```